# Amchart horizontal scrollbar in x axis

Tags: amcharts, jsfiddle

we are trying out amcharts for data visualization and we are using 3D cylinder-chart and we would like to know whether is there a way to set horizontal scroll bar in x axis. Because in the below example, we see there are only 15 items (country's) in X axis but in our data we have nearly 80 to 100. So we would like to have some horizontal scroll bar. Any help on this would be appreciated.

--> https://www.amcharts.com/demos/3d-cylinder-chart/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create a scrollbar in v4, you have to create a `am4core.Scrollbar` instance and assign it to the chart's `scrollbarX` property.

```
// ...
chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();
// ...
```

Here's an updated version of the chart with the scrollbar added

```js
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart3D);
chart.paddingBottom = 30;
chart.angle = 35;

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "country": "USA",
  "visits": 4025
}, {
  "country": "China",
  "visits": 1882
}, {
  "country": "Japan",
  "visits": 1809
}, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "visits": 1322
}, {
  "country": "UK",
  "visits": 1122
}, {
  "country": "France",
  "visits": 1114
}, {
  "country": "India",
  "visits": 984
}, {
  "country": "Spain",
  "visits": 711
}, {
  "country": "Netherlands",
  "visits": 665
}, {
  "country": "Russia",
  "visits": 580
}, {
  "country": "South Korea",
  "visits": 443
}, {
  "country": "Canada",
  "visits": 441
}, {
  "country": "Brazil",
  "visits": 395
}, {
  "country": "Italy",
  "visits": 386
}, {
  "country": "Taiwan",
  "visits": 338
}];

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 20;
categoryAxis.renderer.inside = true;
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;

let labelTemplate = categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template;
labelTemplate.rotation = -90;
labelTemplate.horizontalCenter = "left";
labelTemplate.verticalCenter = "middle";
labelTemplate.dy = 10; // moves it a bit down;
labelTemplate.inside = false; // this is done to avoid settings which are not suitable when label is rotated

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ConeSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "visits";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";

var columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
columnTemplate.adapter.add("fill", (fill, target) => {
  return chart.colors.getIndex(target.dataItem.index);
})

columnTemplate.adapter.add("stroke", (stroke, target) => {
  return chart.colors.getIndex(target.dataItem.index);
})

chart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

**Edit**

In v3, just add a [`chartScrollbar`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartScrollbar) to the [chart object](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#chartScrollbar):

```
AmCharts.makeChart("...", {
  // ...
  chartScrollbar: {
    // optional additional config
  },
  // ...
});
```

Demo:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "theme": "none",
  "type": "serial",
  "startDuration": 2,
  "chartScrollbar": {},
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "USA",
    "visits": 4025,
    "color": "#FF0F00"
  }, {
    "country": "China",
    "visits": 1882,
    "color": "#FF6600"
  }, {
    "country": "Japan",
    "visits": 1809,
    "color": "#FF9E01"
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "visits": 1322,
    "color": "#FCD202"
  }, {
    "country": "UK",
    "visits": 1122,
    "color": "#F8FF01"
  }, {
    "country": "France",
    "visits": 1114,
    "color": "#B0DE09"
  }, {
    "country": "India",
    "visits": 984,
    "color": "#04D215"
  }, {
    "country": "Spain",
    "visits": 711,
    "color": "#0D8ECF"
  }, {
    "country": "Netherlands",
    "visits": 665,
    "color": "#0D52D1"
  }, {
    "country": "Russia",
    "visits": 580,
    "color": "#2A0CD0"
  }, {
    "country": "South Korea",
    "visits": 443,
    "color": "#8A0CCF"
  }, {
    "country": "Canada",
    "visits": 441,
    "color": "#CD0D74"
  }, {
    "country": "Brazil",
    "visits": 395,
    "color": "#754DEB"
  }, {
    "country": "Italy",
    "visits": 386,
    "color": "#DDDDDD"
  }, {
    "country": "Taiwan",
    "visits": 338,
    "color": "#333333"
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
    "position": "left",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0
  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "balloonText": "[[category]]: <b>[[value]]</b>",
    "colorField": "color",
    "fillAlphas": 0.85,
    "lineAlpha": 0.1,
    "type": "column",
    "topRadius": 1,
    "valueField": "visits"
  }],
  "depth3D": 40,
  "angle": 30,
  "chartCursor": {
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false,
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false
  },
  "categoryField": "country",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "axisAlpha": 0,
    "gridAlpha": 0

  },
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }

}, 0);
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: We are library3, could you also provide me the information for the same? Sorry for missing this information in my earlier post.

Comment: Well, you did link to the v4 version of the chart. The v3 version is [here](https://www.amcharts.com/demos-v3/3d-cylinder-chart-v3/). I updated my answer.

Comment: thank you that seems to work. But the navigation icon in the scrollbar is not getting rendered properly. Any idea why so? Here is how it looks like https://pasteboard.co/HPqMD0A.png

Comment: Did you change or move your images folder? Did you update [`pathToImages`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#pathToImages) to point to the new folder?